# GTK3 Spinner while making HTTP requests in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I seen a lot, on the Internet and even [this](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html) official tutorial hasn't solved my issue.

I need a way to make HTTP requests, while Gtk.Spinner spins. I have so far this:

My class:

```
class SpinnerBox(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         self.spinner = Gtk.Spinner()
         self.button = Gtk.Button()
         self.box = Gtk.Box()
         self.box.pack_start(self.spin, True, True, 0)
         self.box.pack_start(self.button, True, True, 0)
         self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_click) # when user clicks the button
         self.add(self.box)

def query(caller, url):
     requests.post(url, '007') # This part of code takes 10 sec
     GLib.idle_add(caller.spin_it)

    def on_button_click(self): # this runs on button click
        session = threading.Thread(target=query, args=(self, "http://example.com/validate"))
        session.daemon = True
        session.start()

    def spin_it(self):
        self.spinner.start()
```

But this solution DOESN'T WORK! It does requests first (without spinning), then AFTER REQUESTS ARE DONE it actually starts spinning. How can I make it spinning, while doing requests (can be more than one) ?

Answer (score 0):

UPD: Okay, seems that I should run spinner first, then create Thread, i.e good solution is:

```
def on_button_click(self): # this runs on button click
    self.spinner.start()
    session = threading.Thread(target=query, args=(self, "http://example.com/validate"))
    session.daemon = True
    session.start()
```